# How to create default AWS VPC using terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way to create default AWS VPC using terraform?

`aws_vpc` resource doesn't have any attribute to mark VPC as default.

I know I can use aws-cli `aws ec2 create-default-vpc`, but that's outside of the terraform.

Comment: Have you deleted the default VPC for a region? Or are you just wanting to start managing it with Terraform?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the default one, which has been created with the aws account. Now without it I cannot create RDS instances.

Comment: Why do you need a default VPC instead of just any VPC?

Comment: Because of this other error: `Error creating DB Instance: InvalidSubnet: No default subnet detected in VPC.` To my best knowledge default subnet can only be created in the default VPC.

Comment: You should create an RDS subnet group in the non default VPC and tell AWS to use that subnet group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it looks like you can't via TF, you can adopt an existing default VPC but not create it:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_vpc.html.

So use the AWS cli to recreate it (if you can) and then use this new provider to adopt it.

Comment: If you read the comments this is more of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and while this does strictly answer the question it doesn't show what they really want to know. Ideally the OP would edit their question to show their real question (about being unable to create an RDS instance without a default VPC in the region) rather than this question/answer combo which is less useful for others who find themselves in the same situation.

Comment: I tend to answer the questions that's actually asked, besides hes deleted the VPC and that's going to need fixing.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR regardless that it seems `xy problem`, the question stands the same. Based on my reading of the docs and comments in the [github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4959) this answer is the right one. I probably should delete misleading comments.

Comment: You don't need a default VPC for a region at all so it's fine to delete (or AWS wouldn't let you do it).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR,  yes, I don't need one and I'm not arguing with you. But I could solve my problem by having one (also suggested by terraform), though terraform lacks functionality to create default subnet or vpc.

Answer (score 5):

A default VPC comes with a public subnet in each Availability Zone, an internet gateway, and settings to enable DNS resolution.

As 17-August-2022, it is possible to create a default VPC through Terraform on AWS in the current region.

It is as simple as:

```
resource "aws_default_vpc" "default" {
    tags = {
        Name = "Default VPC"
    }
}
```

Some important points to note: (As mentioned [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/default_vpc))

- The `aws_default_vpc` resource behaves differently from normal resources in that if a default VPC exists, Terraform does not create this resource, but instead "adopts" it into management. If no default VPC exists, Terraform creates a new default VPC, which **leads to the implicit creation of other resources** (e.g. Subnets, Internet Gateway etc.).
- By default, `terraform destroy` does not delete the default VPC but does remove the resource from Terraform state. Set the `force_destroy` argument to true to delete the default VPC.